# Expander.IsExpaned only if current template is a descendant of a ToolTip

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, findancestor

I am using a `DataTemplate` (a `StaticResource`) in several places in my application as in an `ItemsControl`, `ContentControl` and in a `ToolTip`.

The template contains an `Expander`, and I want its `IsExpanded` property to be true if the `DataTemplate` is located within a `ToolTip`.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks for the parent tooltip, if there is no parent tooltip, it will be evaluated to nothing = false:

```
<Expander Name="expJobContacts" 
    IsExpanded="{Binding IsVisible, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}, 
        Mode=OneTime}" />
```

I tested and it works.